# scrollToPosition() in onCreate() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In method `changeWeek()` I'm trying to scroll elements in my recyclerView. When this method calls after click on menu item in `onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)`. But when this method called in onCreate() it doesn't work :(
Is there any way to fix it?

```
private void changeWeek(int week, boolean fromStart) {
        showSchedule(week);
        if (week == 1) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.first_week) + " " + groupName.split(" ")[0].toUpperCase());
        } else {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.second_week) + " " + groupName.split(" ")[0].toUpperCase());
        }
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(remainder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you call this method on `OnCreatedView` if there is a fragment? Maybe you need the view to be created first.

Try it.

Comment: it's not a fragment

Comment: ok, then try it to put it in the onStart method. In the onCreated I guess you put it under super.OnCreated() , right?

Comment: i forgot that i fill my recyclerView in other Thread, so i need to put scrollToPosition() in this thread... That was just my mistake. Thank you a lot for trying to help me :)

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it !